# Как склеить две картинки используя анимацию, переходы и вывести в видео формат

Tags: javascript, c#

Хочу написать небольшой кусок кода для склейки двух и более картинок используя анисацию, переходы и вывести это в видео. Код будет использоваться для веб сайтов, вопрос в том что с чего начать? Какой ЯП для этого падойдет? Хотелось бы кросс платформеность.

Comment: Для начала напишите видеоредактор для дестопа, потренируйтесь, так сказать, на кошечках:) Время даром не пройдет, большинство ваших наработок пригодятся в вебе. Да, и с необходимой функциональностью разберетесь. А вообще грядет эра WebAssembly. Пока напишите свой дестопный вариант глядишь и его уже можно будет вставить прямо в браузер безо всяких  напрягов, вот уже и библиотеку соответствующую пилят - [WasmWinforms](https://github.com/roozbehid/WasmWinforms)

Comment: @Bulson спасибо.

Comment: Начать с изучения матчасти и разбирательств, что вообще такое MP4 и AVI

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо за отзыв. Что такое видео форматы то я знаю но не знаю в каком направлении двигаться.

Comment: Я бы начал с видеоплеера. Если вы можете проигрывать видео - то уже можно играть другими функциями. Язык... с++, потому что на с++ есть FFMpeg и там много чего написано. Опять же, смотря до какой степени деталицации вы хотите делать обработку. Возможно на с# можно сделать обвёртку над ffmpeg и тогда с++ не нужен.

Comment: @nick_n_a как бы вам объяснить я не думаю написать видео редактор, я пытаюсь написать скажем взять две картинки анимированной их склеить в одну и вывести в видео. Да вы правы с++ тут будет нужен так как все равно нужно буден.